# oracle alias in where clause

Tags: oracle, alias

I am inside oracle procedure

I have a complex query with join which gives single value to which i assign alias

now can i pass alias in where clause in another query rather than making above query again as subquery?

Comment: Please expand your question with some details.  Show us the sort of query you're talking about, and how you want to use this variable in another query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, provided its in scope (ie a subquery you're joining to in the FROM clause that the WHERE exists in).